# Trying to do a simple Insert Into ... Select From ... getting 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric'

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the title states, I am trying to do a pretty simple `Insert Into ... Select From` ... routine.  I am getting this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I ran the `IsNumeric` function on the five columns that are numeric and nothing was returned. Somehow, though, SQL Server is throwing a fit over something here... I just can't tell what the issue is.

I can convert everything to varchar, but that doesn't really solve the problem here.  Is there a best practice for debugging something like this? I have Googled this and I have tried a couple different ideas, but now I am stuck.

Here is the SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO Price_Test2 (ID_RE_GLOBAL, ID_CUSIP,
                         PX_BID, PX_MID, PX_ASK, PX_CLOSE,
                         SPREAD, CRNCY, Provider, AsOfDate, rn)
    SELECT 
        x.ID_RE_GLOBAL, x.ID_CUSIP, 
        x.PX_BID, x.PX_MID, x.PX_ASK, x.PX_CLOSE, 
        x.PX_SPREAD, x.CRNCY, x.Provider, x.AsOfDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.ID_RE_GLOBAL, x.AsOfDate ORDER BY x.ID_RE_GLOBAL) as rn
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             C_LONG.asset_id AS ID_RE_GLOBAL, 
             C_LONG.cusip AS ID_CUSIP, 
             CASE 
                WHEN C_LONG.bid_price LIKE '' 
                   THEN '0'  
                   ELSE C_LONG.bid_price 
             END AS PX_BID, 
             CASE 
                WHEN C_LONG.mean_price LIKE '' 
                   THEN '0' 
                   ELSE C_LONG.mean_price 
             END AS PX_MID, 
             CASE 
                WHEN C_LONG.offer_price LIKE '' 
                   THEN '0' 
                   ELSE C_LONG.offer_price 
             END AS PX_ASK,
             CASE 
                WHEN C_LONG.closing_price LIKE '' 
                   THEN '0' 
                   ELSE C_LONG.closing_price 
             END AS PX_CLOSE,
             CASE 
                WHEN C_LONG.bid_ask_sprd LIKE '' 
                   THEN '0' 
                   ELSE C_LONG.bid_ask_sprd 
             END AS PX_SPREAD,
             C_LONG.currency_cd AS CRNCY,
             'RE_C_LONG' AS Provider,
             C_LONG.themonth + '/' + C_LONG.theday + '/' + C_LONG.theyear As AsOfDate
         FROM
             RE_C_LONG_2018 AS C_LONG
         WHERE 
             C_LONG.asset_id IS NOT NULL
             -- '0x0003f5000d1c2ec9',
             -- '0x001005c706310107',
             -- '0x0010051a84db01b2',
             -- '0x001005c827880293')
         ) x

---- intermediate --
INSERT INTO Re_Price_Intermediate (ID_RE_GLOBAL, 
    ID_CUSIP,
    PX_BID,
    PX_MID,
    PX_ASK,
    PX_CLOSE,
    SPREAD,
    CRNCY,
    Provider, 
    AsOfDate,
    rn)
select *
from
(
select ID_RE_GLOBAL, 
    ID_CUSIP,
    PX_BID,
    PX_MID,
    PX_ASK,
    PX_CLOSE,
    SPREAD,
    CRNCY,
    Provider, 
    AsOfDate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ID_RE_GLOBAL, AsOfDate order by ID_RE_GLOBAL, AsOfDate)
    from Price_Test2
) x
where x.rn = 1
```

Comment: Please do share with us the query.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function. Don't use it. use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` if you want check if a value will convert to the numerical data type you're using.

Comment: Without the query, the table and in short any sort of detail at all on what's happening, there's little we can offer in the way of an answer. One easy pitfall to stumble into is that when you are mixing expressions of different type, you may be surprised to find strings getting implicitly converted to numbers, instead of the other way around, as the numeric types have higher precedence. The other is that `ISNUMERIC`, per Larnu, has many strings it "correctly" considers "numeric", but *for some numeric type you aren't using* (`'$'` is a valid `MONEY`, for example.)

Comment: +1 for not using `ISNUMERIC` see [this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/) for 15 reasons why. It's probably a $ symbol or something like that in your data.

Comment: I just updated my original post.  It's a little bit ugly, but it works on several tables perfectly, with small changes, pointing to different source tables.  It's only puking on one single source table.  I don't know why.

Comment: To me, your `case` statements are the culprit. Put `then 0`, don't put single quotes around the `0`.

Comment: Your `CASE` statements will "always work" thanks to how you've written them, but the result of those may still be invalid values if the input strings aren't valid. Take note of the base types of your columns, and explicitly `CONVERT` / `TRY_CONVERT` them to the appropriate type. If you are ever unsure, you can use `SQL_VARIANT_TYPE(<expression>, 'BaseType')` to get SQL Server to tell you what it has determined the type of something is (which can be unclear if you're mixing types in an expression).

Comment: I ran the select part, without the insert part.  There are over 100M records popping up.  It is really, really hard to eyeball the issue.  I am hoping to find something more definitive.  So far, I'm not seeing anything useful.

Comment: You need to create a select statment to debug this. Use TRY_CONVERT on all the numeric columns and add a where predicate with TRY_CONVERT(YourColumn) IS NULL. If you have multiple numeric columns add more predicates to the where clause using OR. This requires some effort to isolate because you are moving data from one place to another and they have mismatched datatypes.

Comment: You claim "I ran the IsNumeric function on the five columns that are numeric and `nothing was returned`.", but [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) say "ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0.". Conclusion: something is wrong!

Comment: I ran 5 separate queries; selected all and hit the F5 key.  Something is definitely wrong here.

Comment: I applied the ISNUMERIC() function to the five troublesome fields, in the Select part, and it worked.  I was going to switch to the TRY_CONVERT function next, but in this case I didn't need it.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You should still switch to `TRY_CONVERT`. `ISNUMERIC` should just never be used any more; it truly is awful.